# jade's buffer technique (exclamation mark)

Tags: buffer, pug

In github's jade documentation, it talks about the buffered technique:

Code buffered by = is escaped by default for security, however to output unescaped return values you may use !=:

```
p!= aVarContainingMoreHTML
```

I don't quite understand the use of exclamation mark here, I mean, why not just use:

```
p= aVarContainingMoreHTML
```

In fact, I don't quite understand the usage of the buffer technique, there isn't much related to it in the doc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the `!`, `p= aVarContainingMoreHTML` would render brackets as `&gt;` and `&lt` whereas `p!= aVarContainingMoreHTML` would render the var as HTML. You should only use `!` when you really need to.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, now I understand it more (especially the term 'escape')